# Crear linea punteada en medio de div con css

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap-4

Quiero replicar este efecto con css:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente lo estoy haciendo de manera manual con `boostrap` con el siguiente codigo:

```html
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-12 bg-dark text-center">
            -------------------------------------------------------------------
        </div>
    </div>
```

El problema aquí es que no es responsivo. La linea brinca si la pantalla es mas pequeña. Hay manera de hacer esto en css? Tengo muy poco conocimiento y lo que he encontrado no me funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podés reemplazar el color default de borde del elemento hr que trae bootstrap, algo así:

```css
hr {
  width: 95%;
  height: 0;
  border: medium none;
  border-top: 1px dashed white!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 bg-light text-center">
    algo de texto
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 bg-dark text-center">
    <hr/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente solución amigo. Y va de la mano con la estructura que estoy manejando.